# How to send a texture with Agora Video SDK for Unity

Tags: agora.io

I'm using the package Agora Video SDK for Unity and I have followed these two tutorials:

https://www.agora.io/en/blog/agora-video-sdk-for-unity-quick-start-programming-guide/

https://docs.agora.io/en/Video/screensharing_unity?platform=Unity

Up to here, it is working fine. The problem is that instead os sharing my screen, I want to send a texture. To do so, I'm loading a png picture and trying to set it to the mTexture you find in the second link. It seems to be working on my computer, but it is like it doesn't arrive to the target computer.

How can I send a texture properly?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

did you copy every line of the code from the example as is?  You may not want to do the ReadPixel part since this reads the screen.  You may just read the raw data from your input texture and send it with the PushVideoFrame every update.